# HTML audio in iframe (IPAD safari) not working

Tags: html, ipad, iframe, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I have a html reader which uses iframe to dynamically load the html pages.
I'm using HTML5 audio tag(for the navigation button) in the reader html which works well on the "ipad safari", but the audio inside the iframe loaded htmls are not playing.

Below is the reader html structure.

Reader.html

```
<body class="spread-body">
<div class="container">
<div id="page" class="page passage">
<iframe id="frame2" class="frame frame2" src="" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<div class="banner-bottom"><img src="images/banner.png"/></div>
</div>

<div id="pageno"></div>
<input type="button" id="next" class="next-style"/>
<input type="button" id="prev" class="prev-style"/>
</div>
<audio src="engine-audio/chime.wav" id="chime"/>
</body>
```

script in content.html[iframe loaded page]

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
var aud=document.getElementById("init");
aud.play();
});
```

script in Reader.html

```
next_button.addEventListener('mousedown',function(){
document.getElementById('chime').src='engine-audio/chime.wav';
document.getElementById('chime').play();
$(this).addClass('clickedn');
});
```

so, the question is the navigation audio is playing but the audio in the iframe loaded pages are not playing.

pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the "audio" in line

audio src="engine-audio/chime.wav" id="chime"

is recognizable?